# encodeURIComponent not working with Twitter button

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm currently trying to make an app that tweets out the quote that's currently in the text bubble. However, when I use this line of code,

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text" + encodeURIComponent(quote.quote + ' - ' + quote.author);>Tweet</a>
```

It doesn't take me anywhere. Is there any way I could get this working or would I need to use an external Twitter button?

Thanks!

CodePen Link: http://codepen.io/Jelani/full/rOmrOJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed javascript in your markup like that. One approach you could take would be to add some code to your `randomQuote` function like this:

```
var randomQuote = function() {
  ... // current code
  var text = quote.quote + ' - ' + quote.author;
  $('.twitter-share-button').attr('href', "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(text));
}
```

Another approach would be to move your `quote` variable declaration out of the `randomQuote` function and set an `onclick` on the `twitter-share-button`

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" onclick="goTweet()">Tweet</a>
```

that calls a function that does something like:

```
function goTweet() {
  var text = quote.quote + ' - ' + quote.author;
  window.location.href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" +  encodeURIComponent(text);
}
```